# what can be used instead of readLine() in android studio

Tags: android, deprecated, readline

'readLine()' is deprecated less...
this is the error which is shown when i am using readLine() in android studio. What can be used instead

```
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                String line = null;
                while((line = in.*readLine()*) != null)
                {
                    msg = msg + "\n Client : " + line;
                    handler.post(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            chat.setText(msg);
                        }
                    });
                }
                in.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

For read by lines, try BufferedReader:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
```